# Sql multiple max value in different dimensions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a max number of the value but the thing is my code choose only max value even though values are equal so how can I find max value and if there are same make a two rows

Here is the example:
(Ps; data is fake just for example question please let me if something is wrong)

```
select class.name as className, 
       school.schoolName as schoolName, 
       count(school.quantity) as totalNumber from class
join School on school.schoolName = class.schoolName
group by classname, schoolName
order by schoolName
```

and result is:

```
className | SchoolNAme | TotalNum 
 -----------|------------|---------- 
  Math      | A          |        9 
  Bio       | A          |        2 
  History   | A          |        7 
  Music     | A          |        9 
  Math      | B          |       22 
  English   | B          |        8 
  Music     | B          |        1 
  History   | B          |        2 
  Geo       | B          |        2 
  Bio       | B          |        3 
  Math      | C          |       15 
  Geo       | C          |        2
```

and I found each school max number like this:

```
select ClassName, 
       SchoolName, 
       max(totalNumber) as Total
from 
(
  select class.name as className, 
         school.schoolName as schoolName, 
         count(school.quantity) as totalNumber from class
  join School on school.schoolName = class.schoolName
  group by classname, schoolName
  order by schoolName
) t1
group by schoolName
```

and this is the result I have:

```
className | SchoolNAme | Total 
 -----------|------------|---------- 
  Math      | A          |        9 
  Math      | B          |       22 
  Math      | C          |       15
```

but the problem I have as we can see two total number is `9` for `school A`
so how can I show all max number if they are equal.

this is what I want;

```
className | SchoolNAme | Total
 -----------|------------|---------- 
  Math      | A          |        9 
  Bio       | A          |        9
  Math      | B          |       22 
  Math      | C          |       15
```

Thanks

Comment: Hazard a guess at what's missing here

Comment: Yes, I changed from original data that I do not want to share. Only question that I want to know how can I see multiple max value in same column values. Might my question makes complicated

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Max** will show 1 row per group, as you are grouping by school name and there are 3 schools you will get 3 groups and therefore the 3 rows returned.

School A class Bio appears from your data to have only 2 rows (**count** counts the rows per group) so Bio A 9 will never be returned, so the result wanted will never be obtainable. I guess you really expect **Music A 9 instead** along with ***Math A 9***.

The **School** table is actually redundant in this case (based upon interpretation of the join and the ensuing data i.e. count is count the number of joined rows and thus the number of class rows).

As such i believe the following produces the results that you are after :-

```
WITH 
    cte1 AS
        (SELECT name,schoolName, count() AS cnt FROM class
        GROUP BY name,schoolName),
    cte2 AS 
        (SELECT name, schoolName, max(cnt) AS m FROM cte1 
        GROUP BY schoolname)
-- SELECT * FROM cte2
SELECT cte1.name, cte1.schoolName, cte1.cnt FROM cte1  
WHERE cte1.cnt = (SELECT m FROM cte2 WHERE cte2.schoolname = cte1.schoolname)
ORDER BY schoolName, name
;
```

The above was tested using the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS school;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS class;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS school (schoolName TEXT, quantity INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS class (name TEXT, schoolName);
INSERT INTO school VALUES ('A',1),('B',1),('C',1);
INSERT INTO class VALUES 
('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),('Math','A'),
('Bio','A'),('Bio','A'),
('History','A'),('History','A'),('History','A'),('History','A'),('History','A'),('History','A'),('History','A'),
('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),('Music','A'),
('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),('Math','B'),
('English','B'),('English','B'),('English','B'),('English','B'),('English','B'),('English','B'),('English','B'),('English','B'),
('Music','B'),
('History','B'),('History','B'),
('Geo','B'),('Geo','B'),
('Bio','B'),('Bio','B'),('Bio','B'),
('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),('Math','C'),
('Geo','C'),('Geo','C')
;



select class.name as className, school.schoolName as schoolName, count() as totalNumber from class
join School on school.schoolName = class.schoolName
group by classname, school.schoolName
order by schoolName, totalNumber DESC
;

select ClassName, SchoolName, max(totalNumber) as Total
from 
(
  select class.name as className, school.schoolName as schoolName, count(school.quantity) as totalNumber from class
    join School on school.schoolName = class.schoolName
    group by classname,school.schoolname
    order by schoolName
)
group by schoolName;

WITH 
    cte1 AS
        (SELECT name,schoolName, count() AS cnt FROM class
        GROUP BY name,schoolName),
    cte2 AS 
        (SELECT name, schoolName, max(cnt) AS m FROM cte1 
        GROUP BY schoolname)
-- SELECT * FROM cte2
SELECT cte1.name, cte1.schoolName, cte1.cnt FROM cte1  
WHERE cte1.cnt = (SELECT m FROM cte2 WHERE cte2.schoolname = cte1.schoolname)
ORDER BY schoolName, name
;
```

### Results

#### First Query

The first query is your query, the results match the results in the question :-

[image]

#### Second Query

Again this matches the unwanted/wrong results from your question :-

[image]

### Third Query

This I believe matches what you require :-

[image]